# python list of dict find value starts with

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Hi I have a list of dict

```
Player_list = [{'FirstName': 'Rad', 'AId': 178518, 'LastName': 'Nain'},
               {'FirstName': 'Lad', 'AId': 178519, 'LastName': 'Rain'},
               {'FirstName': 'Mad', 'AId': 178520, 'LastName': 'Tain'}]
```

and I want to find for example the position in the list of a key 'lastName' begining by Rai

thanks for your help

Comment: I know this is answered already, but I'm still curious: are you looking for the position of a single dict with a LastName starting with "Rai", or the positions of all such dicts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rais = [i for i,d in enumerate(Player_list) if d['LastName'].startswith("Rai")]
```

Output:

```
>>> Player_list = [{'FirstName': 'Rad', 'AId': 178518, 'LastName': 'Nain'},
...                {'FirstName': 'Lad', 'AId': 178519, 'LastName': 'Rain'},
...                {'FirstName': 'Mad', 'AId': 178520, 'LastName': 'Tain'}]
>>> rais = [i for i,d in enumerate(Player_list) if d['LastName'].startswith("Rai")]
>>> rais
[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
[item["LastName"][:3] for item in player_list].index("Rai")
```